# Flask File Manipulation

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to figure out how to open, manipulate and re-save an uploaded file in flask. I've got it so I can upload the file but then opening it and doing what I want with the data is not happening.

here is what I have...

```
with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename), 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename), 'wb') as outputFile:
        outputFile.write(content.lower())
        outputFile.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

And here is the whole app.py file...

```
import os
from flask import *
from werkzeug import secure_filename

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = '1234'

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'uploads/'
app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['txt'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

# Route that will process the file upload
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    # Get the name of the uploaded file
    file = request.files['file']
    # Check if the file is one of the allowed types/extensions
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        # Make the filename safe, remove unsupported chars
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        # Redirect the user to the uploaded_file route, which
        # will basicaly show on the browser the uploaded file

        with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename), 'r') as f:
            content = f.read()
            with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename), 'wb') as outputFile:
                    outputFile.write(content.lower())
                    outputFile.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

    return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nested with statements, the file that you open at the outer statement needs to be closed first before you can open it again for writing:

```
with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename), 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()

# At this point, the file is closed
with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename), 'wb') as output:
    # do stuff
```

You also don't need to save it, because the loop will close (that is, save and write to the disk) the file once all the statements within the body of the loop are executed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I made the changes but the file still isn't being manipulated?

Comment: Sorry, you were correct, I found another issue - thanks for your help!!